# How to Run this Code on front page only, not on subpages of Wordpress Index?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to show last 5 modified posts from a specific category called "Featured" on the front page just below the regular posts, but not on the subsequent subpages. I am using this code to show these last five posts. Everything seems to be working fine except these 5 posts also run on the subpages.

```
function modified_postsbycategory() {
  // the query
  $the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'category_name' => 'featured', 'orderby' => 'modified', 'posts_per_page' => 5 ) ); 

  // The Loop
  if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
  <?php
  while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
    $the_query->the_post();

            get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'modified' );

        // End the loop.
        endwhile;

    // If no content, include the "No posts found" template.
    else :
        get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' );

    endif;
    ?>
  <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
  <?php
}
  // Add a shortcode
  add_shortcode('categoryposts', 'modified_postsbycategory');
```

I am using this conditional tag just after the function starts, but I think I am not doing the right way.

```
<?php if (is_front_page() && !is_paged() ){ ?>
```

Could you please help me?

PS: Please check the code too and correct me if any errors found. I am just a learner, not expert.

Answer (score 0):

In Wordpress Front page can be either

- Your latest posts
  OR
- A static page

IF it is **Your latest posts** then condition will be

```
<?php if (is_home()){ ..... } ?>
```

Otherwise

```
<?php if (is_front_page()){ ..... } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you just need to check if it's a front page

```
<?php if (is_front_page()){ ?>
```